# Chemistry Rebuses

Tags: rebus, chemistry

These rebuses aren’t original but I quite liked them when I first saw them so I’ll share them here. The first 2 are probably well known, but the last one is slightly more challenging.

1. > abcdefghijklmnopqstuvwxyz
2. > hijklmno
3. > [image]

<sub>*Note that none of the images belong to me.</sub>

Comment: Has a rebus trend started while I've been away? Can't say I'm not pleased about it!

Comment: I like to keep a folder for puzzle ideas/nice puzzles - and to be honest, rebuses are easier to come up with than other ones in my opinion.

Comment: Well keep on posting! I enjoy them...

Comment: \*Knowledge of British English terminology required!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For number 1, it's

> 'R' Gone -- Argon

Number 3 is

> Car Bon<s>net</s> --  Carbon

Comment: Correct. Just the last one to go.

Comment: Nice one. I'll accept yours, as number 3 was supposed to be the most challenging.

Comment: Another one - if letter x was missing it could be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOx

Answer (score 5):

For number 2, it's

> Water - "h" to "o" = $H_2O$.

Comment: Correct. Just the last one to go.

Answer (score 5):

For number 3, I believe it's

> bon

Because

> bonnet - net = bon

Comment: I don't think bon relates to chemistry in any way. But I've a feeling you might be the first one to get the hardest one before any of the others.

Comment: @QuestionAsker has it something to do with ions and their 'Net' electric charges?

Comment: No, I'm afraid. Note that I am not very good at chemistry, but still can appreciate these rebuses. :)

Comment: Ok thanks, thought that might be a bit hard but now that's the only thing I can think of when I look at the net

Comment: Yeah, I was stuck on that one for a while.